# jQuery: Masonry gutterwidth issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I'm having a small, but quite irritating issue while using gutterwidth's on a masonry layout. I'm appending content to a clearing div (after every row) on a click function, then reloading the masonry to include it in the grid. The small issue is though, that when a div is clicked, it seems to chop off the right of the container for a second or so, which looks like a mistake, it occasionally makes the container jump down.
I noticed when taking the `gutterwidth` property out of the jquery and replacing it with `margin-left` and `margin-right` styles this solved the problem, but I preferably need to use gutterwidths as I'll be adding multiple sizes divs (including 100% width) so I don't want any gaps.
Here's a jsfiddle demo (look on the right hand side of the container when a div is clicked): http://jsfiddle.net/SzK5F/5/ 
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var $container = $('#block-wrap');

    $(function(){
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $('#block-wrap').masonry({
            itemSelector : '.content-block-small, .content-block-big, .listing-item, .preview-listing:not(.excluded)',
            columnWidth: 3,
            gutterWidth: 15,
            isFitWidth: true,
            isAnimated: true
            });
        });
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".listing-item").click(function () {

        $('.listing-properties').hide();
        var previewForThis = $(this).nextAll('.preview-listing:first');
        var otherPreviews = $(this).siblings('.preview-listing').not(previewForThis);
        otherPreviews
            .addClass('excluded') // exclude other previews from masonry layout
            .hide();
        previewForThis
            .removeClass('excluded')
            .append($('#property' + $(this).attr('hook')).show())
            .hide()
            .delay(400)
            .fadeIn("slow");
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: previewForThis.offset().top-20 }, "slow");
        }, 500);
        $('#block-wrap').masonry('reload');
    });

});
```

It might be something really obvious that I'm missing, or it might not be able to be fixed at all while using the gutter widths (hopefully it can) but it's just a bit irritating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is happening because when you click on an a block to add the item it is applying the css element `overflow:hidden` to the id `#block-wrap`. If you add `overflow:visible!important` to the css styling, it will overcome this issue.

I've done a quick search through all the attached .js files and your script, but I can't find where the `overflow:hidden` is being added... but the css override I mentioned above doesn't seem to cause any extra issues.

Here is a [fixed fiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/SzK5F/6/)

```
#block-wrap {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 30px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   overflow:visible!important;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew it would be something simple like that. Cheers for your help, much appreciated.